# lwjgl Display.Update() is very slow

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, display

I have a problem with the Display.update(); function in lwjgl. This function take about 64ms to render and all the rest of my code take about 1ms to render. I don't know why it's takes this time.And i have search on internet some information but without result.
Here is my Display init.

```
try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.setTitle(title);
        Display.setResizable(true);
        Display.sync(60);
        Display.create(new PixelFormat().withDepthBits(24),attribs);

        GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);


        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have trying to remove some lines but they make no difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have testing and I have seen after 10 second the Display.update(); take 0 ms to execute. But a new functino take 50 mx to execute. It's very strange.